# Why does R output 2 and not 8 here?

Tags: r, subset

I create a dataframe and select the subset with a value higher than x. But when x = 50, r outputs 2 and not 8:

```
input <- readLines('stdin')
x <- as.integer(input[1])

data <- data.frame(
"id" = c(1:10),
"grade" = c(75, 26, 54, 90, 86, 93, 
48, 71, 66, 99)
)

hscores <- subset(data,grade>x)
print(length(hscores))
```

Comment: `subset(data,grade>50)` returns 8 rows for me. But `length(hscores)` doesn't return the number of rows but the number of columns. I think you are looking for `print(nrow(hscores))`.

Comment: Avoid reading in from the clipboard b/c it's prone to error and not reproducible. Why can't you just assign 50 to x?

Comment: Yes thank you Martin I understand now. Also, thanks Eyayaw, noted.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

`length` when used on a dataframe returns number of columns in a dataframe which is 2 in this case. To count number of rows you can use `nrow` or `NROW`. You can also pass a vector to the `length`.

```
nrow(hscores)
#[1] 8

NROW(hscores)
#[1] 8

length(hscores$id)
#[1] 8
```

Answer (score 1):

We may also do

```
library(dplyr)
hscores %>%
   summarise(n = n()) %>%
   pull(n)
```